# Counting How Many variable that Count a word (PHP)

Tags: php, variables

I want to ask about how to count how many variable that contain a word.

For example, I have 3 variables:

```
$var1 = "Alpha Beta Cupcake Doughnut";
$var2 = "Cupcake Doughnut Eclair Froyo";
$var3 = "Gingerbread Doughnut";
```

And I want the result is like this ("The word" : "How times" - "variable(s)"):

```
Alpha : 1 - $var1(only 1 variable contain word Alpha)
Beta : 1 - $var1
Cupcake : 2 - $var1 and $var2 (2 variables contain word Cupcake)
Doughnut : 3 - $var1, $var2, and $var3(3 variables contain word doughnut)
Eclair : 1 - $var2
Froyo : 1 - $var2
Gingerbread : 1 - $var3
```

Does anyone know how to do this?
I'm really appreciate if there's a sample code for this solution

Comment: Best way would be to explode them into an array then loop through the array word by word testing each variable, saving the count as you go.

Comment: Did You have sample code for this? I'll really appreciate that.

Comment: Someone has done the work for you in an answer, but this looks like some sort of school project.  You don't learn as much by not figuring it out yourself.

Comment: I'm new at PHP, it's not my school project, and I'm learn it by myself alone, and I want to create my own app... Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explode Your variable strings into arrays and then just count entries.
The simplest way, I suppose:

```
$arrayWithVariables = array_count_values(array_merge(
        explode(' ', $var1), 
        explode(' ', $var2), 
        explode(' ', $var3)
    ));
```

Resulting array is:

```
array
  'Alpha' => int 1
  'Beta' => int 1
  'Cupcake' => int 2
  'Doughnut' => int 3
  'Eclair' => int 1
  'Froyo' => int 1
  'Gingerbread' => int 1
```

Comment: Very simple code... Thank You very much... I want to ask another question, is there possible to print the variable that contain the word?

Comment: @CrossVander, yes, You can use string function `strpos()` for this. Like: `if (strpos($var1,'Alpha') !== false) {
    echo '$var1 contains "Alpha"';
}`

Answer (score 4):

- you put variables in array

> ```
>    $variables = array();
>     $variables[] = $var1;
>     $variables[] = $var2;
>     $variables[] = $var3;
> ```

- you create an array holding count for each word

> ```
> $words = array();
> ```

- you count words

> ```
> foreach($variables as $variable)
> {
>   $wordsInVariable = explode(' ',$variable);
>   foreach($wordsInVariable as $word)
>   {
>     if(isset($words[$word])
>     {
>        $words[$word] += 1;
>     }else
>     {
>        $words[$word] = 1;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

- print result

> ```
> print_r($words) // or whatever
> ```

Comment: GREAT! exactly what I want.. Thank You very much... By the way, is there possible to print the variable that contains the word?